# How to detect if webp images are supported via CSS

Tags: css, webp

How do you detect in CSS if webp images are supported?

```
.home-banner-background {
     background-image: url('img/banner.jpg');
 }
 /*Here is an if statement that will check if webp is supported*/ {
        .home-banner-background {
            background-image: url('img/banner.webp');
        }
}
```

Is there an "if" statement which can do that?

Comment: Pretty sure that is impossible to “detect” using CSS alone.

Comment: There are no if statments in css. If something is not supported it simply ignores that rule. A missing image or not supported image will not be ignored since the css is valid.

Comment: Only "if statements in CSS" can test property support only -- `@supports (property: value){/*rules*/}` -- not image file format support.  It would be nice to be able to do `@supports (background-image: url('existing-image.webp')){/*...*/}` but for quite obvious reasons this doesn't work.

Comment: Here working solution example
https://stackoverflow.com/a/64048033/1266559

Comment: Re: _"There are no if statments in css."_ Both `@media` and `@supports` represent `if` structures.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use [Modernizr](https://modernizr.com/). It is a tool that detect 
available features on the user's browser. It is just a script to add in your website, and with it, you can write something like that :

```
.no-webp .home-banner-background {
     background-image: url('img/banner.jpg');
 }

.webp .home-banner-background {
     background-image: url('img/banner.webp');
}
```

Comment: For clarification, the answer to the question is "CSS cannot currently directly check if the browser supports webp." This solution uses JavaScript with CSS.

Answer (score 18):

The [modern webkit browser](https://caniuse.com/#search=%40support) will use the WebP background image with this CSS:

```
.map {background-image: url('../img/map.jpg');}
  @supports (background-image: -webkit-image-set(url('../img/map.webp') 1x)) {
    .map {background-image: -webkit-image-set(url('../img/map.webp') 1x) }
  }
```

Comment: Didn't work for me. Safari 13.1.3 seems to support `-webkit-image-set` but does not support webp and thus it still tries to load it, but can't.

Answer (score 13):

Use the `type()` function together with `image-set()` to provide alternative image formats with CSS.
In the example the `type()` function is used to serve the image in WEBP and JPEG formats. If the browser supports webp, it will choose that version. Otherwise it will use the jpeg version.

```css
.box {
  background-image: image-set(
    url("large-balloons.webp") type("image/webp"),
    url("large-balloons.jpg") type("image/jpeg"));
}
```

[Doku](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/image-set()#using_image-set_to_provide_alternative_formats)

Comment: This solution has very poor browser support at the moment.

Comment: Thanks for adding this answer! It can be helpful for people who only need to target specific browsers. I will bookmark and keep an eye on the browser compatibility over the next year - it looks promising... https://caniuse.com/mdn-css_properties_background-image_image-set

Comment: Don't forget the fallback: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/image/image-set#providing_a_fallback

Comment: This could be the right answer but it lacks -webkit-image-set and fallback for old browsers. Please, read nice article at MDM: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/image/image-set#using_image-set_to_provide_alternative_image_formats

Answer (score 6):

This is currently not supported with CSS.

In the [CSS Images Module Level 4 Draft](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-images-4), a fallback solution is suggested, but this is currently not supported anywhere. ([2.4. Image Fallbacks and Annotations: the image() notation](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-images-4/#image-notation))

But if it will become part of a standard in some years, you then might be able to write:

```css
.home-banner-background {
    image:image('img/banner.webp', 'img/banner.jpg')
}
```

Until then you need to use tools like Modernizer, as suggested in the answer of [Fifi](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57359447/1960455)

Alternatively, the `picture` HTML tag might something you could think of, but if that is usable in your case depends on how the image should resize on your site:

```html
<picture>
  <source srcset="img/banner.webp" type="image/webp">
  <source srcset="img/banner.jpg" type="image/jpeg"> 
  <img src="img/banner.jpg">
</picture>
```

Comment: The irony is that when browsers support image notation, they'll almost certainly support webp too.

Answer (score 3):

You could actually just add it to the original declaration without needing multiple classes, `@supports`, or bringing in another library similar to this:

```
.home-banner-background {
    background-image: url('img/banner.jpg');
    background-image: -webkit-image-set(url('img/banner.webp') 1x,
                                        url('img/banner-2x.webp') 2x),
                                        /* etc */;
}
```

Webkit will use the `webp` images and all others will fallback to the regular image.

Comment: Safari also supports `-webkit-image-set` but not webp. This will fail on iOS

Comment: Ah, good call. In some situations recently, I've been checking for user agent, and using the appropriate image format based on that. Can't wait till there's a better way.

Comment: Checking the "Accept" header for "image/webp" is much better than guessing based on the user agent

Comment: Pretty sure that both images will be downloaded then and then it totally defeats the purpose of decreasing the size with webp...

Answer (score 1):

This solution works well:

```css
.home-banner-background {
  background-image: url('img/banner.jpg');
}

@supports (gap: 1px) {
  .home-banner-background {
    background-image: url('img/banner.webp');
  }
}
```

Targeting just browsers which support the gap property ensures a very similar browser support to WebP images.
REF: https://caniuse.com/flexbox-gap

Answer (score 0):

For now (Q1 2023) using `image-set` is not a sufficient solution because lots of devices that actually support WebP won't get be able to use it. There is a large difference in support coverage of both feature.

I'd opt for Modernizr but it is not tree-shakeable. Code below might be useful to set [a class](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57359447) on `<body>` or use directly in the image wrapper or directive.

```
// inspired by Modernizr implementation
function supportsWebP() {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    const image = new Image();
    image.onerror = () => resolve(false);
    image.onload = event => resolve(event.type === 'load' && image.width === 1);
    image.src = 'data:image/webp;base64,UklGRiQAAABXRUJQVlA4IBgAAAAwAQCdASoBAAEAAwA0JaQAA3AA/vuUAAA=';
  });
}
```

```
// example usage
const useWebP = await supportsWebP();
const backgroundImage = `/img/picture.${ useWebP ? 'webp' : 'png' }`;
```